# Axiom of Extensionality and defining the notion of set equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have the AOE as:

$\forall A\,\forall B\,(\forall X\,(X\in A\iff X\in B)\Rightarrow A=B)$

and possibly its converse? I am not sure of the technical details.

I am confused as to why this implies equality, instead of defining it. Currently, I am reading through *Naive Set Theory* by Halmos. So far, in this set theoretic 'universe' we are constructing, we only have the notion of belonging ($\in$) and a set as a collection of 'things'. So, how can we bring in $=$ without defining it?

Comment: Equality is usually considered a basic part of the logic, and not something that needs to be added in the theory.

Comment: Note that if equality isn't part of your underlying logic, two sets being coextensive is not a good notion of equality; you could have $A$ and $B$ being coextensive, but $B\notin\{A\}$. If you want to define equality, you need an additional axiom ensuring that $A$ and $B$ being coextensive implies that they are also members of exactly the same sets.

Comment: Can you provide and example?

Comment: @pmac An example of what?

Comment: An example of two sets $A, B$, that are coextensive but $B \not\in \{ A \}$.